# Function returning the solution and "None", how to remove the "None" being returned

Tags: python

In my code I cannot understand why python is returning a `None` at the end. I have tried to close every statement with `Exit` however I am still getting the `None`. Here is the output I am getting:

```
[[6 4 5 3 2 8 7 1 9]
 [3 8 7 9 1 6 4 5 2]
 [2 9 1 4 5 7 6 3 8]
 [5 6 3 2 9 1 8 7 4]
 [9 7 8 6 4 5 1 2 3]
 [1 2 4 8 7 3 5 9 6]
 [7 3 9 5 6 4 2 8 1]
 [8 5 6 1 3 2 9 4 7]
 [4 1 2 7 8 9 3 6 5]]
None
```

Here is my current code, could I kindly ask some assistance to identify where I am missing it:

```
import numpy as np
import copy

def sudoku_solver(sudoku):
    start_sudoku = copy.deepcopy(sudoku)
    duplicates(sudoku)
    solution(start_sudoku, sudoku)

def duplicates(sudoku):
    for r in range(9):
        line = (sudoku[r, :])
        nonzeros = [x for x in line.flatten() if x != 0]
        if (len(nonzeros) == len(set(nonzeros))) == False:
            array = [[-1 for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
            return (np.array(array))
    return

def solution(start_sudoku, sudoku):
    for y in range(9): 
        for x in range(9): 
            if sudoku[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10): 
                    if possible(y, x, n):
                        sudoku[y][x] = n
                        solution(start_sudoku, sudoku)
                        sudoku[y][x] = 0 
                return
    if np.array_equal(sudoku, start_sudoku):
        array = [[-1 for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
        return np.array(array)
    return sudoku

your_solution = sudoku_solver(sudoku)
print(your_solution)
```

Comment: To "remove" a None value being returned, return something else (or just don't print the returned None value).

Comment: an `exit()` directly after return will never hit and is useless. So my best guess whithout diving in too deep is that you hit the returns in solution, most likely in the if equal block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sudoku_solver` function does not `return` anything, so the default is `None`, and then in the next line you `print` that `None`.

So remove all `exit()` from your functions, and remove the `print` you have in there, and make sure the function returns the solution:

```
def solution(sudoku):
    for y in range(9): 
        for x in range(9): 
            if sudoku[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10): 
                    if possible(y, x, n):
                        sudoku[y][x] = n
                        result = solution(sudoku)
                        if result is not None:  # Get out of recursion: we have a solution!
                            return result
                        sudoku[y][x] = 0 
                return  # No solution here
    # If we get here, we have filled the sudoku completely: return it
    return sudoku
```

And return that also in `sudoku_solver`:

```
def sudoku_solver(sudoku):
    if duplicates(sudoku):
        return  # Not valid
    return solution(sudoku)
```

And `duplicates` should return a boolean: `False` = no duplicates, `True` = duplicates.  I will leave that for you to do as it is not difficult to change the code in that way.

### Addendum

From your attempts and edits to the question, it turns out you still have `return` statements without any value, or no `return` statements at all.

Here is a working version:

```
def possible(y, x, n):
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if sudoku[y][i] == n:
            return False
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if sudoku[i][x] == n:
            return False
    x0 = (x // 3) * 3
    y0 = (y // 3) * 3
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            if sudoku[y0 + i][x0 + j] == n:
                return False
    return True

def duplicates(sudoku):
    for row in sudoku:
        row = [x for x in row if x]
        if (len(row) != len(set(row))):
            return True # there are duplicates
    for i in range(9):
        col = [row[i] for row in sudoku if row[i]]
        if (len(col) != len(set(col))):
            return True # there are duplicates
    for i in range(0, 9, 3):
        for j in range(0, 9, 3):
            box = sudoku[i][j:j+3] + sudoku[i+1][j:j+3] + sudoku[i+2][j:j+3]
            box = [x for x in box if x]
            if (len(box) != len(set(box))):
                return True # there are duplicates

def solution(sudoku):
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if sudoku[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10):
                    if possible(y, x, n):
                        sudoku[y][x] = n
                        result = solution(sudoku)
                        if result is not None:
                            return result
                        sudoku[y][x] = 0
                return
    return sudoku

def sudoku_solver(sudoku):
    if duplicates(sudoku):
        raise ValueError("Invalid Sudoku: it has duplicates")
    return solution(sudoku)

sudoku = [[0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 8, 7, 1, 9],
 [3, 8, 7, 9, 1, 6, 4, 5, 2],
 [2, 9, 1, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3, 8],
 [5, 6, 3, 2, 9, 1, 8, 7, 4],
 [0, 7, 8, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 3, 5, 9, 6],
 [7, 3, 9, 5, 6, 4, 2, 8, 1],
 [8, 5, 6, 1, 3, 2, 9, 0, 7],
 [4, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 3, 6, 5]]
your_solution = sudoku_solver(sudoku)
print(your_solution)
```

Comment: I removed all Exits and added the return, however I am still getting the None

Comment: Yes, there are more problems. Updated answer.

Comment: I have tried everything even worked down the function to its very basic form and added return to each one, however I am still getting `None`

Comment: Oh wait. You removed all the essential information from your question. That is not good. Please put that back, or this answer makes no sense anymore. I'll help you further if you can do that.

Comment: I added the information again as requested

Comment: I rolled back your question to an earlier version, as there were functions missing you had in your original question. I have added a section to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I however am still getting the following error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: ----> 3 your_solution = sudoku_solver(sudoku)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237320/discussion-between-n-k-and-trincot).

Comment: It seems like you used my code with numpy arrays. The code I posted is running just like it is. See it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/sudokuqa)

Comment: However, if you use numpy, the `if result:` should become `if result is not None:`. I have updated my answer with that.

Comment: That works, thank you, thank you very much it is truly appreciated trincot

Answer (score 0):

As `sudoku_solver` function does not return anything `your_solution` will be None. The solved table is printed in `solution` function.
At the end you are printing `sudoku_solver` which is None.

Answer (score 0):

your_solution runs the function sodoku_solver(), which does not have a return statement. In python, a function with no return statement returns None. So by printing the your_solution, you are printing None.

If you want the solution returned in the function sodoku_solver(), return sodoku in solution() and change the last line in the sodoku_solver() function to return solution(start_sudoku, sudoku)